# Как скопировать репозиторий и файлы определенного типа командой cp [BASH]

Tags: linux, bash, консоль

Я хочу скопировать все файлы с расширением **.txt** из папки **testdirectory** в папку **results** (эти две папки лежат в одной директории). Если в папке testdirectory есть папка, а в ней тоже файл расширения .txt, то его тоже нужно скопировать (вместе с папкой)

Я пытался сделать это следующим образом (запускаю в папке testdirectory):

`cp -R *.txt ../results` 
но в таком случае копируются только файлы в ~testdirectory (то есть внутренние папки не трогаются и файлы в них тоже)

Если так:
`cp -R ../testdirectory/ *.txt ../results` то копируются абсолютно все файлы и папки (то есть копируются файлы с другим расширением, что не нужно)

UPD: ищется решение именно через команду cp

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2503

Comment: Во второй команде лишний пробел

Comment: @Эникейщик где именно?

Comment: Между именем папки и звездочкой. Получается два аргумента и поэтому копируется все.

Comment: @Эникейщик я пробовал убирать его, получается как в первой ситуации. Только файлы из самой папки. Внутренние не копируются.

Comment: `*.txt` - тут баш подставляет под звездочку все файлы из текущей директории. Поэтому подкаталоги не будут работать. Я думаю через cp это сделать невозможно. Выше вам подсказали rsync. `rsync -am --include='*.txt' --include='*/' --exclude='*' testdirectory results`

Comment: @TotalPusher а если не сохранять папки, а только одни файлы?

Comment: В смысле все файлы положить в одну кучу без иерархии? Вроде в rsync нет такой опции. Тогда нужно использовать `find ... -exec cp ...`

Comment: @TotalPusher а можно поподробнее?

Comment: `find testdirectory -name '*.txt' -exec cp {} results \;`. Если цель - версионирование, можно использовать git, исключив все файлы, кроме `*.txt`, а если в проекте уже есть гит - нужно просто сделать кое-что хитрое (команде гит можно указывать каталог)

Comment: Одной командой `cp` это сделать невозможно.

Comment: @TotalPusher А что в таком случае делать с файлами с одинаковым именем? С точки зрения задачи, я могу слегка изменить их имя (например, счетчик к концу имени или еще как-то), но не могу найти способ реализовать это хоть как-то технически. Например, $RANDOM выдает всё время одно и то же число внутри find

Comment: `$RANDOM` - переменная баша, она подставляется один раз, поэтому как вы хотите работать не будет. Вот скажите, зачем все файлы сливать в один каталог? Вы сами себе усложняете жизнь, и скорее всего вам нужно другое решение.